# phonegap android app icon wrong resolution

Tags: android, cordova

I've been working on an android phone app over the last couple of weeks using phonegap, and everything has been great.

Today, I rebuilt the app to test some requests to the server and I noticed that the app icon on my phone had shrunk, to a tiny size.

I've been version controlling my app so I tried rebuilding the app from some older versions, and the same thing, the app icon was still tiny.

The only thing I know for sure is that the app icon was not always this tiny, and just last week I had the icon the right size. I'm not sure what happened and why new builds of the application are not making the icon the right size.

Does anyone know if phonegap just had a recent update that would change the icon size or know what the problem might be..?

Here's what my config file looks like

```
<icon src="logo.png" />
<icon gap:density="ldpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" />
<icon gap:density="mdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" />
<icon gap:density="hdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" />
<icon gap:density="xhdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" />
```

Comment: are you building locally or through build.phonegap.com?

Comment: through the build.phonegap.com site, I'm also testing on a galaxy s4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Galaxy S4 is xxhdpi resolution. You need to add the xxhdpi resolution (144px).

Here the full list (px):

- ldpi: 36 x 36.
- mdpi: 48 x 48.
- hdpi: 72 x 72.
- xhdpi: 96 x 96.
- xxhdpi: 144 x 144.

Comment: 144px was added on Android (devices) with the Galaxy S4 generation, like HTC One and others. You have the xxxhdpi too, but there is no device yet with this resolution.

Comment: The initial build on phonegap only came with the 4 example pics and I definitely had a galaxy s4 then... that's why I was wondering when they added a bigger image

Comment: I don't know why phonegap forgot about the xxhdpi resolution. Your device or phonegap builder could adapted xhdpi resolution to your device (I'm just guessing). But now you know, don't forget about the xxhdpi ;)

Comment: Too bad cordova 3.6.3 silently discards your xxhdpi setting when creating the config.xml for Android platform with the `cordova build android` command.